# Is it correct to end a sentence with "still"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

I've seen *still* used at the end of a sentence a lot of times. For example

- "I love you, still"
- "I would recommend you to do that, still"

Etc. Is it correct to use *still* this way?

Comment: If what you're trying to do is use ***still*** in the sense *nevertheless; all the same* (i.e. - *despite* some unspecified contextually relevant factors implying that I might *no longer love you*, the enduring fact is that I ***do***), the normal position for the adverb would be *I **still love** you.*

Comment: Do they have to have commas?

Comment: "I love you still" is virtually a fixed expression, with 'still' meaning 'to this very day'. The comma is rarely seen and arguably incorrect. This (terminal) positioning of temporal 'still' is poetic / archaic and has a very restricted distribution (even "I adore you still" sounds unacceptable). // Initial positioning for temporal 'still' is archaic/poetic and usually requires do-support and inversion (Still do I love thee). Concessive 'still' placed in initial position requires the usual offsetting comma. Medially positioned  'still' ("I still love you") may be either concessive or temporal.

Comment: Much more contemporary-feeling, with the OP sense (*I continue to be.../I remain*...), when placed at the beginning - "Still crazy after all these years" (P. Simon); Are you still angry with me?; He's still banging on about...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Excellent summary. That said, in my Greater Toronto Area dialect at least, it can appear at the end of a sentence in spoken conversation either because it's an afterthought or is moved for emphasis: "I'm tending the garden, still" or "I'm planning to go to the mall still; want to join me?" In writing neither of those reasons applies so it stays preverbal.

Comment: Yes; [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/still) has a usage note: << Spoken English:
In informal speaking, you will often hear _still_ used in end position. Many speakers of English may consider this usage too informal:

_I can’t find my bag still. Has anyone seen it?_ / 

_Have you got their address still?_ >>. I'm obviously one of this particular many. It sounds non-standard to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not common. The CED must be mistaking, where can one often hear it? Is it a dialect thing?

Comment: @SovereignSun I'm afraid I must discount opinions as to idiomaticity from someone who uses 'The CED must be mistaking, where can one often hear it?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Excuse me, but if it's really common why don't people often hear it?

Comment: @SovereignSun Perhaps the researchers at CED have done more work and more thorough work on the subject than people just speaking from their more limited experience. They use corpus studies. Do you? // I've been a native speaker for over 60 years, and have rarely if ever come across '... must be mistaking ... '.  Not a recommendation for the writer to be taken seriously, and neither is your comma splice.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

This construct is used to clearly emphasize that the stated condition continues to be valid and accurate.

It is frequently used after the listener has expressed some doubt.

> In Puerto Rico, thousands are without power, still.  This is despite thousands of hours of work.
>
> Wait, you buy DVD's...still?  Everyone else just watches NetFlix.

It's just a different way to emphasize the temporal aspect of the activity.

**The downvotes on this Answer are completely invalid and wrong and should be ignored.  Especially since there is no comment.**

Comment: I disagree. Even in speech I would never say that. I'd say something like, "**I love you. I still do**". It's not at all frequently used as you state.

Comment: @SovereignSun Sorry, but this answer is complete correct.  OP even indicated seeing this multiple times.

Comment: Instead of just asserting that your answer is correct, maybe finding credible sources that support your answer and editing your answer to include them would be a better approach. If one person has a doubt, there are probably more that will read this in the future and have the same doubt.